Run a web socket on Cloud Functions for a loraWAN webhook
I am developing an open-source GPS collar for livestock using LoRa and LoRaWAN to transmit GPS data to The Things Network (TTN) database. However, this data is not retained in TTN, so I need to create a database to store my GPS data. Therefore, I created a cloud function with Firebase to retrieve this data, store it, and display it on an HTML page with a satellite map background (Maps JavaScript API). However, I want to have bidirectional communication (receive uplinks and transmit downlinks) from my HTML page, so I am trying to use WebSockets to handle this operation. However, I can no longer deploy my cloud function. I also understand that WebSockets rely on a continuous connection, unlike cloud functions, and that while it is possible to implement them, there is a risk of incurring high costs from frequent function calls. Does anyone have any suggestions for implementing a client-server-TTN-gateway-node protocol that allows real-time bidirectional communication? (There would be minimal data transmission since it relies on LoRa technology.) Thank you very much.
I tried to use websockets on a firebase cloud function to show uplinks in an HTML client page but i cannot deploy my function with "ws".
